# Error when trying to deploy SharePoint 2010 solution package - SharePoint 2010 - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: deployment

when i try to deploy the project from VS 2010 i get this below error....

`Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm`

Comment: You should try to run Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: Check all causes at [Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/07/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-recycle-iis-application-pool-the-local-sharepoint-server-is-not-available-check-that-the-server-is-running-and-connected-to-the-sharepoint-farm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got this error today.  I was using the CKSDEV plug-in for Visual Studio and trying to deploy my dll to the GAC.  The project was developed on my machine and I was working on integrating it with a developer's code on another machine.

In this situation, the "Site" property for the project did not reference a site on this particular server.  I set the site property to the proper location and the project deployed without issue.

[image: Project Properties Window]

Comment: Hi Rich, could you give me the step by step, i am new to this SP

Comment: @Abu - sure this is easy once you see it, but tricky the first time. In the Solution Explorer, highlight your project by just clicking on it once.  From the View menu, select the Properties Window.  In the Properties Window, there is a property for Site URL.  Make sure this points to a site that exists on this machine.  I'll add a picture to the answer above.

Comment: I am following all above step but i get the following error: > An object in the SharePoint administrative framework,
> "SPSolutionLanguagePack Name=0 ", depends on other objects which do
> not exist. Ensure that all of the objects dependencies are created
> and retry this operation

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the user you are running the Visual Studio with is part of the db_owner group on the sharepoint_admin and sharepoint_config databases in SQL Server.

Check this for more details:

http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/19/resolving-vs-2010-solution-deployment-issues-for-sharepoint-2010-projects/